# Azure Devops YML pipeline error for aws keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, key

I am getting below error while running Azure DevOps Pipeline. I have added correct AWS 'Access key' and 'Secret Access key'. However it is still failing.

I checked from backend windows server. It is working fine manually but giving below error when I run the pipeline. Not sure what is missing, can please you suggest ?

**Note:** I am using IAM role to access the AWS environment and providing 'keys' of same role

> An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
> Cannot index into a null array.

Comment: Which task in Azure DevOps is producing this error?

Comment: There is a pipeline to deploy windows service to aws ec2 instance and aws access key and secret access keys are being used

Comment: Check the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html and create a new AWS service connection to check the status.